# Best Way to add footer view in Xamarin forms list view?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I noticed that Xamarin forms ListView doesn't have a method similar to addFooterView in Android.

I want to add a submit button at the bottom the list.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own **custom renderer** for **Xamarin.Forms** **ListView**, and add in the ability to expose the **addFooterView** in **Android** perhaps?

This would be the simplest way of extending the support for this on the **Android** platform specifically.

**Update 1**

To achieve something that is applicable across all platforms you could customize the cell appearance based on the data it represents.

In **Xamarin.Forms** you are able to write your own custom **Cell** implementations that can be used in a **ListView** or **TableView**.

Therefore to achieve the '*Load More*' effect at the bottom of the **ListView**, you could add an extra **Model** item into your collection, with some flag indicating that it is this type of display to be shown, rather than the normal **Cell** representation of a real **Model** item.

Evaluating this flag, you would be able to determine whether you should show the '*Load More*' custom view or not.

When you are going to add more data, naturally you would **remove** this item, **prior** to adding new items, and then also add this '*special case*' **Model** item afterwards.

Comment: Can you think of any platform agnostic way of doing it?

Answer (score -1):

you can do it the way Pete described or in a non ListView related way. If i had to implement a fixed footer i would put a ListView and a StackLayout into a grid with two rows. The ListView's row has a *asterisk height and the StackLayout an Auto sized height.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Text="Your fixed footer"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

**Update**
If you need a customizable cell on the bottom of the ListView then you can simply use the Footer property of the ListView.

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="Some Titles"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.Footer>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Footer of the ListView"/>
    </StackLayout>               
</ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```